# How to integrate Flash and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, flash, dynamic, integration

tutorials (e.g. ) show how to integrate Flash and MySQL. Also Flash can manipulate and sent this back to server (http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/create_edit_xml.htm).

To integrate flash and MySQL one can do the following:

(1) MySQL -> php -> Flash (e.g. (http://)library.creativecow.net/articles/brimelow_lee/php_mysql.php) - bracketed url as I am only allowed one hyperlink per question as a new user!
(2) Flash -> php -> MySQL (e.g. http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/create_edit_xml.htm)

What is the most robust way to set up (1) and (2) to work at scale - as quickly as possible? What are the server loading implications? Is there any other way to do (1) and (2) more effectively?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is hard to understand the question. What are the approaches you are trying to compare? On what merits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Flash PHP MySQL tutorial.

http://library.creativecow.net/articles/brimelow_lee/php_mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible for Flex to talk directly to MySQL or any database, for that matter.  You must use web services in conjunction with [HTTPService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html)
or use something like [Spring BlazeDS](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex). In general, your concerns about scale should focus on whatever web service/server side configuration you pursue.  In these cases the same rules apply as in your average web applications: use proper database indices, use caching if you're running the same queries repeatedly (and your data is not changing that quickly), denormalize if your joined queries are bogged down, shard or partition your if your tables have locking issues or have grown too large to easily back up and manage.